# Different sizes for application logo - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, stage

I would like my JavaFX application to use different icons in Windows for the taskbar and the title bar of the window. The first one should be 32x32, while the other one 16x16.

I tried to set multiple icons to the `Stage` like this:

```
stage.getIcons().addAll(logo32, logo16);
```

...but it uses the image `logo32` both in the taskbar and the title bar.
This seems something that should be very simple and very common also, so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. I am using JavaFX 13.

The icon pointed at in this screenshot should not be the same as the one in the taskbar:

[image: d]

Comment: Can you make a self-contained example? Does the order you add the icons matter?

Comment: Looking at the javadoc "The images should be different sizes of the same image and the best size will be chosen, eg. 16x16, 32,32." They suggest 16x16 and 32x32, but those might not actually be the best. So maybe the 32x32 is the best for both the title bar and task bar.

Comment: I tried with different sizes, for example using 64x64 and 8x8, but the biggest one is always used

Comment: No, the order does not seem to matter